# Log property change

Tags: c#, logging, properties, fody

There are many models in my app to keep it simple like this:

```
class Foo
{
    public int Bar { get; set; }
    public string BarName { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like to add verbose level logging to each set of every property in every model. Like:
Property {Name} {OldValue} -> {NewValue}

AS I said there are many model and many properties so changing each one is not possible. Is there a way to do it with aspects like fody and attribute?

Comment: Check out this link about `INotifyPropertyChanged` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification

Comment: You would need [`INotifyPropertyChanging`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanging.propertychanging(v=vs.110).aspx) as well if you want to capture the previous value. The problem is you need to add code to each property to call them (or use a base class, but still requires some code in the property). There are frameworks like [Fody](https://github.com/Fody) that can decorate properties with attributes and inject code at run-time/compile time.

Comment: And yes, Fody's [PropertyChanged](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged/wiki/BeforeAfter) aspect has a Before/After pattern that you can follow to get an event that gives both values.